# How can I block or opt-out of installing a dependency with Yarn?

Tags: javascript, npm, gatsby, yarnpkg

I'm using Gatsby, which has a long list of sub-dependencies, some of which I'd like to never allow Yarn to install and execute. Ideally I'd like to be able to add a per-project blocklist, but I'm open to other ways of achieving the same goal of not installing specific packages, even if it leads to errors in the direct dependencies that rely on them.

To be clear, I'm not looking to merely install another version of the same package, but instead to prevent it from being installed at all. If I can replace it with a package I control that is just a shim that'd be a nice solution too.

I've tried using `resolutions` with the package version set to `null`, but this didn't seem to have an affect.

Comment: Have you tried using resolutions with your custom versions of the packages and the [Offline cache](https://yarnpkg.com/features/offline-cache)?

Comment: @HernánAlarcón Can resolutions be used to specify a custom version? Will offline cache work when deps are installed on other machines?

Comment: The [Selective dependency resolutions](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) page literally says: "lets you define custom package versions". The [Offline cache](https://yarnpkg.com/features/offline-cache) page also says: "making it suitable for being stored within a repository, [as we actually do in the Yarn repository itself](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/tree/master/.yarn/cache)", so I guess it will work on different machines as long as they use the same repository.

Comment: Terminology seems to be getting mixed up here. I intend “custom version” to mean code that has not been released as part of the package on NPM, but it appears the Selective Dependency Resolutions docs intend it to mean a specific version that is available on NPM. It doesn't appear that offline cache is a feature of Yarn v1 (at least I couldn't find anything about it in the documentation). Yarn v2 is largely incompatible with major JS tools like React Native or Gatsby.

Comment: Yarn classic **does** have a page about offline mirror: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/offline-mirror

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using resolution and link as version works for me to setup webpack5 instead of webpack4 for storybook.

```
"resolutions": {
    "webpack": "5",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack4": "link:./node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack5"
}
```

In order to completely blocks the package it's possible to link to unexisting folder like: `./node_modules/.cache/null`

https://yarnpkg.com/features/protocols

Comment: it would be: "link:./node_modules/.cache/null" 
Thanks for the tip!